# Problems with Powershell and imageboxes

Tags: powershell

Trying to create a simple GUI Script using powershell to ping a TP ip address and display it with a simple Green/Red Image depending whether its on/off.

But for some reason, when hitting the Close button, I cant seem to remove the green/red dots. 
The File contains:

```
Arial,172.0.0.0
Bodoni,172.0.0.0
Caslon,172.0.0.1
```

---

Script:

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.text = "Hardware Checks"
$Form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(600,600)
$arrayTPs = Get-Content -path "C:\Activity monitor\TPs.txt"
#Image Locations
$filered = (get-item 'C:\Activity monitor\red1.png')
$filegreen = (get-item 'C:\Activity monitor\green1.png')
$imgred = [System.Drawing.Image]::Fromfile($filered)
$imggreen = [System.Drawing.Image]::Fromfile($filegreen)
$outputBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$outputBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,200)
$outputBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(565,200)
$outputBox.MultiLine = $True
$outputBox.ScrollBars = "Vertical"
$Form.Controls.Add($outputBox)
$Button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(450,30)
$Button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,75)
$Button.Text = "Check"
$Button.Add_Click({
$Form.controls.Remove($outputBox)
$Form.controls.refresh()
foreach($room in $arrayTPs){
#Get Name of room from array
$roomAlone = $room -split ","
$roomAlone[0]     
$pictureBoxRed = new-object Windows.Forms.PictureBox
$pictureBoxGreen = new-object Windows.Forms.PictureBox   
#Add room name to textbox
if($roomAlone[1] -eq "172.0.0.0"){
$pictureBoxGreen.Width = 10
$pictureBoxGreen.Height = 10
$pictureBoxGreen.Image = $imggreen
$pictureBoxGreen.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(90,$counterpic)
$outputBox.controls.add($pictureBoxGreen)
$Form.Controls.Add($outputBox)}
else{
$pictureBoxRed.Width = 10
$pictureBoxRed.Height = 10
$pictureBoxRed.Image = $imgred
$pictureBoxRed.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(90,$counterpic)
$outputBox.controls.add($pictureBoxRed)
$Form.Controls.Add($outputBox)
}  
$counterpic = $Counterpic + 20
$counter = $Counter + 20
}})
$Form.Controls.Add($Button)
$cancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$cancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(450,520)
$cancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,25)
$cancelButton.Text = "Close"
$cancelButton.Add_Click({
$outputBox.controls.Remove($pictureBoxRed)
$outputBox.controls.Remove($pictureBoxGreen)
$outputBox.Controls.Equals($null)
$outputBox.controls.update()
$Form.Refresh()
foreach($room in $arrayTPs){
#Get Name of room from array
$roomAlone = $room -split ","
$roomAlone[0] 
$pictureBoxRed = new-object Windows.Forms.PictureBox
$pictureBoxGreen = new-object Windows.Forms.PictureBox
}})
$Form.Controls.Add($cancelButton)
$Form.Add_Shown({$Form.Activate()})
[void] $Form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: `$outputBoxCP` that is not the form name is it? Can you try a `$form.Refresh()` too where `$form` is the name of the form.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but have tried that too, and still nothing.
The images dont seem to get wiped when i do $outputBoxCP.clear() just text do..

Comment: What type is `$outputBoxCP`? i.e. `$outputBoxCP.Clear() usually means clear text, but not necessarily added controls. i.e. You would likely have to iterate trough and remove the added controls.

Comment: @HAL9256 the outputbox is a multi line textbox which contains both text and image, but i cant seem to remove the images